# cant send data from one activity's dropdown-spinner to another activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, runtime, dropdown

I am newbie in android. I want to send what the user has selected in dropdown-spinner in MainActivity.java to SecondClass.java and for that i am using intent but the app is getting forced closed and the log is saying

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hitesh.recommend/com.example.hitesh.recommend.SecondClass}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

**MainActivity**

```
    Spinner dropdown = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    String[] items = new String[]{"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
    dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

    Spinner dropdown1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    String[] items1 = new String[]{"9", "10", "11", "12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items1);
    dropdown1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    String ConcatedString1 = dropdown2.getSelectedItem().toString().concat(dropdown3.getSelectedItem().toString());
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondClass.class);
    intent.putExtra("username",dropdown2.getSelectedItem().toString().concat(dropdown3.getSelectedItem().toString()));
    startActivity(intent);
```

**SecondClass**

```
String string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");
 TextView h2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.src);
 h2.setText(string);
```

again I am kind of in a learning phase. What am i doing wrong here?
Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: try `Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondClass.class);` **or** `getIntent().getStringExtra("username")`

Comment: it worked but the textview is displaying empty body

Comment: try using `+` instead of `concat`

Comment: yupp it worked.... thanks a lot